# Progress bar for an image upload with jQuery $.ajax and Spring Boot

Tags: jquery, spring, cloudinary

I'm having trouble setting a progress bar in a $.ajax post, that uploads an image to the Cloudinary service, via a @Controller with the Spring framework. My problem is that the event, that monitors the upload process has the whole file as uploaded from the beginning.

```
ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 8718, total: 8718,
type: "progress"…}
```

That's my code:

```
 var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
 var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
 $.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend: function(xhr){
          xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
     }
 });
 /*<![CDATA[*/
 for(var i = 0; i < filesList.length; i++){
  /*]]>*/
       var formData = new FormData();
       formData.append("file", filesList[i]);
          $.ajax({
              xhr: function()
                 {
                  var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                  //Upload progress
                  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event){

                      if (event.lengthComputable) {
                          var percentage = Math.round((event.loaded *100) / event.total);

                          $(".progress-bar").css("width", percentage + "%");
                      }
                  }, false);
                  return xhr;
                  },

              url:  "/admin/web/cms/upload",
              type: "POST",
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              data: formData,

              success: function(data) {
                 $(".progress-bar").css("width", "0%");
              }
         });
         console.log(filesList[i].size);
  }
```

As a result of that, the progress bar appears always as completed. 
How can I manage, to monitor the image uploading process, to show it with the progress bar? 
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes, but with a completely different approach. I've posted an extract of the code, that worked for me. I would recomend you to check the Cloudinary documentation, for the function cloudinary_fileupload.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that one, with the `cloudinary_fileupload` function:

```
 $(".cloudinary-fileupload").cloudinary_fileupload({

  ...

     progressall: function(e, data){
          $(".progress-bar").width(Math.round((data.loaded * 100.0) / data.total) + "%");
          $(".progress-bar").text(Math.round((data.loaded * 100.0) / data.total) + "%");

          if((Math.round((data.loaded * 100.0) / data.total) === 100) && filesAmount > -1){
                 $(".progress-bar").text('');
                 $("#uploading").text(processingImatges);
                 $(".progress-bar").addClass("progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated");

                         $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){ 
                         return processingImatges;
                 });
          }
      },
```

With this approach, the progress bar monitors all the images being uploaded at once, not for each single one.